# What do you call a place where a crime is about to happen?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When you say *crime scene* you refer a place where a  crime *happened*. How to refer to a place where a crime is *about* to happen?

Example sentence:

> The police wanted to stop the guy before he reached the ______ with his gun.

Comment: Here, one could use perhaps 'ambush location' or 'targeted bank' (though here, the crime is _not_ 'about to happen').

Comment: Perhaps the "intended location".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you cannot really call it a "crime scene" before the crime takes place, especially if the early arrival of the police might prevent the crime happening at all, in which case it will never be a crime scene. You could therefore call it the "potential crime scene". This succinctly expresses the idea that the location may become a crime scene whilst leaving room for the possibility that it may not.